# Push back object to vector pointer, class of object is into namespace

Tags: c++, object, vector

Main problem is how to add object of a patient into pointer vector.
Class Patient is in namespace Health. Patient has name, last name and number (I used set and get). Vector of pointers I should put to Hospital.

> main section

```
vector<Health::Patient*> patients;

Health::Patient p1("John", "April");
p1.set("1234");

cout<<p1.get();

Health::Patient p2("George", "Best");
p1.set("2351");

patients.push_back(p1); // in this line push_back doesn't work

Hospital h1("DontGoThere", patients);
```

Should I make a new function to add object of patient to vector ?

Comment: You want `vector<Health::Patient> patients;` (no asterisk).

Comment: If you really want `patients` holding pointers to `Patient` you also need `p1` to be of that type: `Health::Patient* p1 = new Health::Patient("John", "April");` but  you need to explicitly free memory when element is popped from your vector doing it this way

Comment: But what then with set and get, they dont work

Comment: @Momo You need to call it `p1->set("2351")` . But consider not using vector of pointers like @PaulSanders suggested - you don't have to care that much for memory management then. Then you need to adjust the constructor of `Hospital`, e.g. `Hospital::Hospital(std::string str, std::vector<Health::Patient> &patients)`

Comment: Task is to use pointers, tnx I don't know how I forgoted -> -_-.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you wrote `p1.set` twice instead of using `p2` in the second time.

Comment: Tnx, I already fix that

Comment: _Task is to use pointers_ Then the task is wrong.

Comment: task is to use pointer vector

Comment: The task is teaching you *bad* C++.

Answer (score 2):

Some different approaches:

1. Keep `patients` as a vector of `Health::Patient*`

   ```
   std::vector<Healt::Patient*> patients;
   Health::Patient *p1 = new Health::Patient("John", "April");
   p1->set("1234");
   ```

   This way you have to care yourself that the allocated memory for every instance of `Patient` will be properly freed, like:

   ```
   // delete last container element
   std::vector<Health::Patient*>::iterator itr = patients.back();

   if (*itr) {
       delete *itr;
   }

   patients.pop_back();
   ```

   And this gets really messy if an instance `Hospital` e.g. also holds a pointer to the freed instance of `Patient`
2. Like 1) you store pointers in your vector but don't allocate `Patient` instances on the Heap :

   ```
   std::vector<Healt::Patient*> patients;
   Health::Patient p1 ("John", "April");
   p1.set("1234");
   patients.push_back(&p1);
   ```

   This comes with the risk that `patients` might go out of scope but you still                               dereference the pointers you passed to your `Hospital` instance for example
3. Don't use a vector storing object pointers:

   ```
   vector<Health::Patient> patients;

   Health::Patient p1("John", "April");
   p1.set("1234");

   patients.push_back(p1);

   // adjust Constructor of `Hospital` so it takes `std::vector<Patient>`
   // as argument (or a reference to it)
   ```

   The advantage here is you can simply call `patients.pop_back()` to remove last element - no need to free memory you allocated on Heap. Memory is automatically freed when vector goes out of scope.

Without knowing your whole code I recommend that `Hospital` owns the actual instances (or a copy) of `Patient` and you directly add your objects there without having a local container but one as a member of `Hospital` (especially if its a container of pointers)

```
void Hospital::addPatient(Health::Patient p) {
   m_patients.push_back(p);
}

Health::Patient p1("John", "April");
p1.set("1234");
h1.addPatient(p1);
```

**Edit: When insisting on using pointers**

For the pointer approach you should make sure that `Hospital` takes ownership of the passed `Patient` instance so memory management is only handled there:

```
// m_patients now of type std::vector<Health::Patient*>
void Hospital::addPatient(Health::Patient* p) {
   if (p) {
        m_patients.push_back(p);
   }
}

Health::Patient *p1 = new Health::Patient("John", "April");
p1->set("1234");

// Hospital takes ownership
h1.addPatient(p1);
p1 = NULL;
```

For this approach it is even better not to use a pointer variable `p1` at all, and improve your constructor of `Patient` so it creates the proper object right away and you don't have to ensure that `p1` can't access it anymore.

```
h1.addPatient(new Health::Patient("John", "April", "1234"));
```

Like shown in 1) you need to ensure the memory is properly freed - the destructor of `Hospital` would be the right place to free all remaining elements within `m_patients` e.g.